# Update Dynamically created text box by name withought looping through all controls (VB)

Tags: vb.net

I have a project that creates several buttons dynamically along with a slider (two splitters in a panel).

For the purpose of this lets call the slider "slider9001" and the label "label9001".  Each set of control's last 4 digits are different.

Currently I'm looping through all of the controls and looking for a label with the last 4 digits of the slider.  This seems incredibly inefficient, especially considering there will be over 100 labels and 40-50 sliders on the form.

Does anyone know of a simple and more efficient way of accessing a dynamically created label

I should mention the slider will be used to update the label

Comment: are you just looking for this one label or is there a larger picture like finding all the labels sort of related to a slider?

Comment: It's just a one to one relationship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the name of the control you can get a reference to it 
Dim lbl as label = 
ctype(me. Controls("label9001"),label)

Answer (score 2):

As the labels are generated, store a reference to each one in a dictionary.  Use the digits as the key.  When you need a label, simply retrieve it from the dictionary.  The same approach will work for the sliders as well.

```
dim labels as new Dictionary(of string, Label)
' add generated labels to dictionary

dim lbl = labels("9001")
```

Answer (score 0):

Outstanding! Since I already know the name

Dim lbl as label = ctype(me. Controls("label9001"),label)

Worked perfectly.  Thanks Much!!!